# A obj2(A tmp) ; What this statement in C++ mean

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

```
class A{

};

int main()
{

A obj(A tmp);  //will this call ctor/dtor?. 

}
```

The program runs without calling ctor/dtor. 
Wondering what this statement means.

Comment: This is a "quirk" in the C++ language.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, that's a function declaration.

Think of it as

```
A obj(A tmp); 
int main()
{

}
```

But with `obj` only visible inside `main`.

Even clearer if you rename a few things:

```
A func(A param); 
int main()
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to consider this case while compiling and testing.